# Fill Subscribers Custom field with fields in a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, subscriber

In Marketing Cloud, I have a custom field in Subscribers that I need to fill the value from another custom field in a Data Extension.

This Data Extension have contacts that will become subscribers, when an email is sent the contact become a subscriber and, also at this moment, I need that custom field in Subscribers to get the custom field's value from the Data Extension.

Any idea how i do it?

Comment: @JacksonChen I have tried only through the Marketing Cloud it self, in Subscriber, Data Extension, E-mail Studio (declarative progamming, I think). But didn't try with code (AMPScript or Server Side Java Script)

Comment: Please provide more specifics on exactly what your use case is and anything you have tried so far (sometimes academic examples really help to clarify). Right now it is too vague for us to be able to help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to write a [SQL query](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) and `JOIN` your data and possible a `CASE` statement but I don’t completely understand what you’re trying to achieve without any examples.

Comment: I don't believe a SQL query would work as they cannot target lists or all subscribers and he wishes to push the info from a DE to All Subs.